# Primeira aplicação utilizando o maven

Tags: java, maven

Em minha aplicação estou tentando utilizar o maven, mas estou com alguns problemas que pode ser relacionadas a configuração, quando vou gerar um JAR do projeto ou utilizar alguma opção de Run As do arquivo pom.xml no terminal o retorno sempre é:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
```

Estou utilizando jdk1.8.0_45, apache-maven-3.3.3 e as seguintes variáveis de ambiente já foram adicionadas: JAVA_HOME e M2_HOME.

*pom.xml*

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>appgeodev</groupId>
<artifactId>simple-map</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>simple-map</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Como está `M2_HOME` e `PATH`?

Comment: M2_HOME esta da seguinte maneira: C:\starcode\apache-maven-3.3.3
 e o PATH : ;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%M2_HOME%\bin;

Comment: Você está executando algo com isto é: `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME`? Como é windows, tentou sem o `$`?

Comment: @BrunoCésar, tentei executar esse comando no cmd com e sem ´$´, da seguinte maneira: _mvn -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME_, mas sem sucesso, o terminal me retorna o seguinte mensagem: Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of the Maven installation

Comment: Esse jeito que colocou com certeza dará erro, por que está sem nenhum `goal`. Tente, por exemplo `mvn clean -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME` e atualize com o erro, testei em um windows aqui e está OK. Se possível, inclua seus `pom.xml`

Comment: @BrunoCésar parece ser um problema na minha configuração, pois quando dou o comando `mvn -version` ele me mostra a seguinte mensagem no terminal: _ERROR: M2_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
M2_HOME = "C\program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4"
Please set the M2_HOME variable in your environment to match the location of the Maven installation_

Comment: Também não consegui rodar seu comando sugerido, meu pom.xml esta bem básico, nada que deveria gerar algum problema

Comment: Esse valor para `M2_HOME` já está diferente do que disse antes, é sim seu ambiente, fica meio difícil reproduzir isto. Veja se o diretório está correto, se está configurado certo, sem estar nas variáveis de usuário, etc.

Comment: Aquela declaração de "C\program Files\apache-maven-3.0.4" é o que o terminal, meu caminho da M2_HOME esta assim: C:\starcode\apache-maven-3.3.3, vou adicionar meu pom.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para não deixar o tópico sem resposta final, acabei resolvendo o problema reinstalando o eclipse para a ultima versão, aparentemente era algum problema com sua instalação pois o maven estava instalado corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa

No seu eclipse acesse:

> Window / Preference / Java / Installed JREs

Selecione o JRE e clique em **Edit**

No campo **Default VM arguments** adiciona:

**-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME**

**Obs.:** Precisa ter o Mave Home setado.